# IEnumerator - Waitforseconds - Error (CS1525)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
IEnumerator () {      // this is were the error is 
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (10);
        characterdirection.SetInteger ("State", 5);
        }
```

This doesn't work and says: Error (CS1525) unexpected symbol '{'

Comment: It incorrect code. Interfaces don't have constructors and its hard to understaand what you're trying to do, its almost like you're trying to have an anon delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You must define a name for your function;

```
IEnumerator WaitAndSetState ()
{    
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (10);
    characterdirection.SetInteger ("State", 5);
}
```

Comment: Does `WaitForSeconds` return an IEnum? *Still good attempt to try and understand*.

Comment: Yeh, it's a yield instruction from the Unity API. See; [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)

Comment: Thanks this helped

Comment: does this go in the void start or void update,  it happens at the start of the game so... sorry i am a noob at coding.    Also Lece your answer has the same problem of Unexpected symbol '('

Comment: There's an example on the page linked in my last comment. Check it out. Also, the snippet I've provided above **is** valid syntax so without more information I'm unable to assist further.

Comment: I have copy and pasted your answer and it still does not work. Is my unity brocken?

Comment: That's always a possibility! :) but let's see... Check that `Animator` has been setup correctly as per the [Animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetInteger.html) docs to ensure `characterdirection.SetInteger ("State", 5);` actually does something we can detect. And if you're still experiencing compilation errors let me know and I'll update my answer with a working (here) copy and paste example for you.

Comment: @W1ll how are you getting on?

Comment: Still having trouble. What I am trying to do is get my character to appear after the animation is finished. The animation play's at the start of the game and goes for 10 seconds, hence the incorrect script above. State 5, is the appear animation for the character. If there is another way to set State to 5 after the animation that would be helpful.

Comment: I DID IT. But a different way. Thanks for your help

Comment: @W1ll Great, but the above script will only call `SetInteger` **after** 10 seconds - that's what yield does. :)